# fix pop3 connector on SBS 2003

Tags: smtp, pop3, windows-sbs, exchange-2003

I am attempting to get our SBS 3003 Server (yes I know it's old and outdated) to retrieve mail from our web mail provider via pop3 and send via SMTP through our web mail provider however I seem to have created a catch 22 I can send or receive but not both

Right now I can send and my smtp server settings are

under exchange configuration wizard > servers protocols > smtp > default virtual server

anonymous access is checked, basic authentication is checked

under advanced delivery:

masquerade domain is set to the @ part of our email, FQDN is set to the .local domain, and smart host is set to smtp.ourwebmailhost.com, outbound security is set to anonymous. under connectors . [smtp connector forward mail through smart host is set to smtp.ourwebmailhost.com] (correction this needs to be set to use DNS) bridgeheads is set to the default smtp virtual server address space is set to smtp * and 1.

the pop3 connector has one mailbox setup
with pop3.ourwebhost.com as the server port 110 user@ourdomain.com as the user name and the correct password and confirm password use SPA is checked mailbox information is set to route to user mailbox and my exchange mailbox Outlook is set up for my exchange account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued my research and found that I needed to add the external domain to the user policy for exchange